# Jmeter - Getting 403 forbidden errors on custom api's while running a login script of sharepoint login

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I'm getting `403 error` on each custom rest api while executing the sharepoint login.

Could you please share with me a solution with an example?

This error comes

> {"error":{"code":"-2147024891,
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access
>   denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access
>   this resource."}}}

Comment: Anybody can suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to add proper authentication context to each API request and the most common way to protect the API from unauthorized usage is requirement to have valid [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header.

Inspect the outgoing requests to your custom API using your [browser's developer tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and pay attention to the [request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) in the "Network" tab, I believe you should see the aforementioned "Authorization" header or [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header or something like this.

In your JMeter script you can add custom headers to your requests using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)

JMeter should handle Cookies automatically given you add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan.